# Setting permissions for gitlab-runner

Tags: linux, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to deploy base build using gitlab-runner. Each build i have the same error `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/test_deploy’: Permission denied`. I've added gitlab-runner user for all possible user groups but it hasn't helped. I'm using **CentOS 7**. Could someone help me to solve this issue or just steer me the right way?

Here is my **config.toml:**

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "https:/link to gitlab"
  token = "token"
  executor = "shell"
  builds_dir = "/var/www/test_deploy/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true
  [runners.docker]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

and here is **gitlab-runner** user groups:

```
root:x:0:gitlab-runner
wheel:x:10:gitlab-runner
tape:x:30:gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner:x:5008:
docker:x:982:gitlab-runner
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was directory owner. After owner changing (for `/var/www/`) it works fine.